# How to return x value from (x,y) coordinates in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def has_x_value(cs,x):
      tuple_convert = list(cs)
      x_values = [x[0] for x in tuple_convert]
      for i in x_values:
         if i == x:
             return True
         else:
             return False
a = has_x_value({(2,4), (1,5), (6,3), (2,2)},2)
b = has_x_value({(14,14), (13,9), (13,16), (10,12)},10)
print(a)
print(b)
```

I am trying to make a function that returns True if the set contains the x-coordinate, False otherwise. I have written the above code, but it returns True for a and False for b, but I don't understand why it returns False for b.

Comment: Dont `return False` in `else`.`return False` at end of `has_x_value`.Think about how you find one thing in many things.Think about what you should  do when you found one item is not what you want.

Comment: un-indent  the lines `else:` and `return False` one step (make it `for ... else`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you `return` in both branches ***inside*** the loop, your current code is equivalent to:

```py
def has_x_value(cs, x):
    tuple_convert = list(cs)
    x_values = [x[0] for x in tuple_convert]
    if x_values[0] == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

As you can see you are only checking the first coordinate.

You need to `return False` only in case ***none*** of the coordinates were found:

```py
def has_x_value(cs, x):
    x_values = [x[0] for x in cs]
    for i in x_values:
        if i == x:
            return True
    return False
```

Which can then be converted to a simpler:

```py
def has_x_value(cs, x):
    x_values = [x[0] for x in cs]

    return x in x_values
```

Or even just:

```py
def has_x_value(cs, x):
    return any(x == coord[0] for coord in cs)
```

---

- Note that the `tuple_convert` is not necessary and you can iterate over the set just the same.